# Changing bokeh grid lines position

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to plot a few points on a graph, similarly to a heat map.

Sample code (adapted from the heat map section [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html)):

```python
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import BasicTicker, ColorBar, ColumnDataSource, LinearColorMapper, PrintfTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import transform
import numpy as np

# change this if you don't run it on a Jupyter Notebook
output_notebook()

testx = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
testy = np.random.randint(0,10,10)

npdata = np.stack((testx,testy), axis = 1)
hist, bins = np.histogramdd(npdata, normed = False, bins = (10,10), range=((0,10),(0,10)))

data = pd.DataFrame(hist, columns = [str(x) for x in range(10)])

data.columns.name = 'y'

data['x'] = [str(x) for x in range(10)]

data = data.set_index('x')

df = pd.DataFrame(data.stack(), columns=['present']).reset_index()

source = ColumnDataSource(df)


colors = ['lightblue', "yellow"]
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=df.present.min(), high=df.present.max())

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title="test circle map",
           x_range=list(data.index), y_range=list((data.columns)),
           toolbar_location=None, tools="", x_axis_location="below")

p.circle(x="x", y="y", size=20, source=source,
       line_color=None, fill_color=transform('present', mapper))


p.axis.axis_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "10pt"
p.axis.major_label_standoff = 10
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 0

show(p)
```

That returns:

[image: test circle map]

Now, as you can see, the grid lines are centered on the points(circles), and I would like, instead to have the circles enclosed in a square created by the lines.

I went through [this](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/grids.html) to see if I could find information on how to offset the grid lines by 0.5 (that would have worked), but I was not able to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built into Bokeh to accomplish this kind of offsetting of categorical ticks, but you can write a custom extension to do it:

```
CS_CODE = """
import {CategoricalTicker} from "models/tickers/categorical_ticker"

export class MyTicker extends CategoricalTicker
  type: "MyTicker"

  get_ticks: (start, end, range, cross_loc) ->
    ticks = super(start, end, range, cross_loc)

    # shift the default tick locations by half a categorical bin width
    ticks.major = ([x, 0.5] for x in ticks.major)

    return ticks

"""

class MyTicker(CategoricalTicker):
    __implementation__ = CS_CODE

p.xgrid.ticker = MyTicker()
p.ygrid.ticker = MyTicker()
```

Note that Bokeh assumes CoffeeScript by default when the code is just a string, but it's possible to use pure JS or TypeScript as well. Adding this to your code yields:

[image]

Please note the comment about `output_notebook` you must call it (possibly again, if you have called it previously) *after* the custom model is defined, due to [`#6107`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6107)

Comment: Yup, that works. I just needed to add
`from bokeh.models import  CategoricalTicker`. Leaving this here just in case someone else has the same issue.

Thanks!